# Large class with dependant classes and shared properties

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns, refactoring

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to refactor a very large C# class and specifically how to pass shared properties/values from the large class into the extracted classes and have those modified values available in the main class.

At the start, this class was 1000 lines long and is very procedural – it involves calling methods and performing work in a specific sequence.  Along the way things are persisted into the database.  During the process there are multiple Lists of items that are worked on and shared in the methods.  At the end of this process, there are a bunch of statistics that are presented to the user.  These statistics are calculated in various methods as the processing is taking place.  To give a rough outline – the process involves a bunch of random selection and at the end of the process the user sees how many random items, how many invalid records were picked, how many items came from this sub-list etc.

I have been reading Uncle Bob’s “Clean Code” and am trying to make sure as I refactor that each class does only 1 thing.

So I have been able to extract methods and classes in order to keep the file smaller (have it down to 450 lines now) but the problem I am having now is that these broken out classes require values from the main parent class to be passed to them and updated – these values will be used for other methods/class methods as well.

I am torn as to which is the cleanest approach:

1)  Should I create a bunch of private member variables to store the statistical values and Lists in the main class and then after calling into the main class' dependnat class methods, receive back a complex result class and then extract these values out and populate / update the private member variables? ( lots of boiler plate code this way)

OR

2)  Is it better to create a DTO or a some sort of container class that holds the Lists and statistical values and just pass it to the various class methods and child class methods by reference in order to build up the list of values?  In other words I am just passing this container class and since it's an object the other classes and methods will be able to directly manipulate the values in there.  Then at the end of the process, that values DTO/container/whatever you want to call it will have all of the final results in it and I can just extract them from the container class (and in that case there really is no need to extract them and populate the main class’ private member variables. )

The latter is the way I have it now but I am feeling that this is a code smell – it all works but it just seems “fragile”.  I know large classes are not great but at least with everything in 1 large file it does seem clearer as to which properties I am updating etc.

-- UPDATE --

Some more info:

Unfortunately I can't post any of the actual code as it is propriatary - will try to come up with dummy example and paste it in if I get some time.  One of the comments below mentioned refactoring the code into steps and that is exactly what I've done.  The purpose of the class is ultimately 1 thing - to create a random list of things - so in the only public method that gets called for this class - I have refactored this down to 1 level of abtraction for each "step".  Each step, whether that is a method in the same class, or if it makes sense to break it out into a helper class to do the substeps - it still requires access to the lists that get built up during the process and the simple counter variables that keep track of the statistics.

-- UPDATE --

Here is an attempt at showing something similar in code:

```
public class RandomList(){

    public int Id{get; set;}
    public int Name{get; set;} 
    public int NumOfInvalidItems {get; set;}
    public int NumOfFirstChunkItems{get; set;}
    public int NumOfSecondChunkItems{get; set;}

    public ICollection<RandomListItem> Items{get; set;}   
}

public class CreateRandomListService(){

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ICreateRandomListValidator _createRandomListValidator;
    private readonly IRandomSubProcessService _randomSubProcessService;
    private readonly IAnotherSubProcessService _anotherSubProcessService;   

    private RandomList _randomList;

    public CreateRandomListService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
                                ICreateRandomListValidator      createRandomListValidator,
                                IRandomFirstChunkFactory randomFirstChunkFactory,
                                IRandomSecondChunkFactory randomSecondChunkFactory){
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _createRandomListValidator = createRandomListValidator;    

    _randomFirstChunkService = randomFirstChunkFactory.Create(_unitOfWork);
    _randomSecondChunkService = randomSecondChunkFactory.Create(_unitOfWork);
}   


public CreateResult CreateRandomList(CreateRandomListValues createValues){

    // validate passed in model before proceeding
    if(_createRandomListValidator.Validate(createValues))
        return new CreateResult({HasErrors:true});

    InitializeValues(createValues); // fetch settings from db etc and build up
    ProcessFirstChunk(); 
    ProcessSecondChunk(); 
    SaveWithStatistics();
    createResult.Id = _randomList.Id;
    return createResult;


}

private InitializeValues(CreateRandomListValues createValues){

    _createValues = createValues;
    _createValues.ImportantSetting = _unitOfWork.SettingsRepository.GetImportantSetting();
    // etc. 
    _randomList = new RandomList(){
        // set initial properties etc. some come from the passed in createValues, some from db
    }

}
private void ProcessFirstChunk(){
    _randomFirstChunkService.GetRandomFirstChunk(_createValues);
}

private void ProcessSecondChunk(){
    _randomSecondChunkService.GetRandomSecondChunk(_createValues);
}

private void SaveWithStatistics(){

    _randomList.Items _createValues.ListOfItems;
    _randomList.NumOfInvalidItems = _createValues.NumOfInvalidItems;
    _randomList.NumOfItemsChosen = _createValues.NumOfItemsChosen;
    _randomList.NumOfFirstChunkItems = _createValues.NumOfFirstChunkItems;
    _randomList.NumOfSecondChunkItems = _createValues.NumOfSecondChunkItems;

    _unitOfWork.RandomThingRepository.Add(_randomList);
    _unitOfWork.Save();
}
}

public class RandomFirstChunkService(){
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public RandomFirstChunkService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork){
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

public void GetRandomFirstChunk(CreateRandomListValues createValues){
    // do processing here - build up list collection and keep track of counts
    CallMethodThatUpdatesList(creatValues);

    // how to return this to calling class?  currently just updating values in createValues by reference
    // can also return a complex class here and extract the values back to the main class' member
    // variables
}

private void CallMethodThatUpdatesList(createRandomListValues createValues){
    // do work

}
}
```

Comment: Maybe Uncle Bob needs to take a valium. Less flippantly, if you're contemplating shipping the internals of the class around to a couple of different new classes, you've broken things up wrong. The object of refactoring is to identify units that can interact with each other relatively simply. Find the groupings of internals that don't need to know about each other and can trade simple outputs; those are your building blocks. Most importantly, if the code *works* now, maybe you should just toss a #region around it and let it be. This is called "redneck refactoring", and it works.

Comment: yes I have done the "redneck refactoring" using the #region tag lol - it's a poor man's solution but does clean up the file somewhat.  Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: You should break it up into "steps" as we both agreed on, but each "step" should either be built on a common base class for the common functionality or a utility class. I'd probably go the utility class(es) route and have one for all the DB stuff and one for each "functional block" -- BUT -- those should be completely independent and not work on each other... i.e. the DB class should be DB only and return something generic to the caller.

Comment: see updated code snippet

Answer (score 1):

The brutal answer is that it depends... of course. It is hard to work out a answer without reading the code, but I would say that once you have created new classes (with one purpose) those classes and interfaces should define what data objects you need to pass around to solve your problems. And in that case it is strange for a method to return the same type as pass into it, I also think that manipulation one object through a seriers of methods is fragile. Imagine if each of you classes was a REST service; then how would those interfaces look like.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't "pass stuff around". Nor would I break it up into separate classes just because its 1000 lines. You'll end up making it much messier and much more of a maintenance headache.

You didn't post your code (duh), so its hard to critique it. If you really go over it, I suspect you might have duplicate code in there that can be refactored into methods, etc.

If you've already gotten rid of the duplicate code, I'd next pull out all the database stuff into a DAL layer.

If you really want to make it smaller (based on what little info you provided), I'd next refactor it into "steps" and make a workflow type parent container class.

Again, hard to say without knowing the code.

Comment: see my Edit above

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly you have managed to refactor the class this far, but from your explanation it sounds to me like the "statistic" is the concept that should become an object, something like:

```
interface IStatistic<TOutput>
{
    IEnumerable<TOutput> Calculate(IEnumerable<input-type>);
}
```

When you wish to display some statistic, you just use the appropriate statistic:

```
return new MySpecial().Calculate(myData);
```

In case that statistics objects are not that easy to construct, e.i. they ask for some parameters and so, then you may supply a Func delegate which creates them:

```
void DoSomething(Func<IStatistic<string>> factory)
{
    string[] inputData = ...
    foreach (string line in factory().Calculate(inputData))
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

As you are mentioning multiple lists, I suppose that input-type would actually be a couple of input types. If that is so, then it might really make sense to supply a kind of a DTO to just hold the lists:

```
class RawData
{
    public IEnumerable<type1> Data1 { get; }
    public IEnumerabel<type2> Data2 { get; }
    ...
}
```

Observe, however, that this is not a DTO "by the book". First, it is immutable - only getters are there. Second, it only exposes sequences (`IEnumerable`), rather than raw lists. Both measures are taken to disallow statistic objects to manipulate data.